# 3d model looks turned inside out

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I use openGl ES 2.0. When I load 3d model, it looks turned **inside out**. The surface inside the model looks perfect. How can I make outer surface look like inner surface?

Thanks in advance!

[image: View on iPhone]

Comment: From the stragen shading it looks more like your indizes for glDrawElements are messed up. Can you show some of your drawing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to reverse the winding order of your polygons. Check out [glFrontFace](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/2.0/docs/man/glFrontFace.xml) and [glCullFace](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/2.0/docs/man/glCullFace.xml)

Answer (score 2):

is depth testing turned on?  try:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

sometime before you render the polygons (preferably do this at opengl initialization time)