# 3d model looks inside out or distorted outside and perfect inside (VULKAN)

Tags: python, vulkan

Any 3d model loaded into my vulkan code is perfect inside and wrong outside.How can I make outer surface look like inner surface?
It is like the same in [3d model looks turned inside out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898855/3d-model-looks-turned-inside-out) question. But the code i wrote is in vulkan and i dont know how to fis it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oXlP.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xe13b.png)

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of your pipeline setup. I expect either wrong winding order and/or wrong depth state setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent of [`glFrontFace`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glFrontFace.xhtml) in Vulkan is setting the
`frontFace` member of the [`VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.html) structure when creating your graphics pipeline.

If you want to change the front face dynamically rather than at pipeline creation time that's possible if the implementation supports `VK_EXT_extended_dynamic_state` or is running Vulkan 1.3, although it may still depend on the underlying driver having support. In that case you'd set the `VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_FRONT_FACE` as a flag in the `VkDynamicState` (again, when creating your graphics pipeline) and then you would need to call `vkCmdSetFrontFace` in pretty much the same way you would `glFrontFace`.

However, all of this is predicated on you having the same problem as the original question you referenced.  You might simply have a different problem which looks similar, in which case without a reproducible example, people are unlikely to be able to help diagnose it.